# retry operation on hot stream?

Tags: java, project-reactor

```
Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
        .doOnNext(__ -> System.out.println("producing number: " + __))
        .publish()
        .autoConnect()
        .doOnNext((Integer __) -> {
            System.out.println("throwing error.");
            throw new RuntimeException("aaa");
        })
        .retry(1, error -> true)
        .subscribe(number -> System.out.println("I will never be here..."),
                error -> System.out.println("will I be here? " + error),
                () -> System.out.println("completed!"));
```

Output:

```
producing number: 1
throwing error.
producing number: 2
producing number: 3
```

Expected output: (From my logic - I'm sure I'm mistaken)

```
producing number: 1
throwing error.
producing number: 2
throwing error.
producing number: 3
```

Why the output is different then the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit tricky but it boils down to this:

Calling `publish` and `autoConnect` has the effect that once you subscribe, an inner subscription is created that persists even if the outer subscription is cancelled. Think of it as two streams connected by `publish` and `autoConnect`.

```
--inner stream--> publish/connect-> --outer stream--> subscriber
```

No matter what happens in the outer stream, the inner stream will continue to run. That's intended because you have a hot observable and you could have more than one subscriber. If one disconnects, then the others still want to have values from the stream. In other words the publish operator tells the source that it can produce values as long as it wishes.

```
    --inner stream--> publish/connect-> --outer stream--> subscriber1
                                        --outer stream--> subscriber2
```

You can verify that behavior by removing `retry`. The numbers 1 and 2 will still be printed. If you want the source to stop producing values you can use `refCount` instead of `autoConnect`. `refCount` cancels the inner stream if there are no more subscribers.

Here comes the tricky part: This stream is synchronous and [Streams are just functions](https://itnext.io/reactive-streams-are-just-functions-da3f2b60753d). It's a bit more complicated under the hood, but the subscribe function inside the retry operator runs until the inner stream completes. Only then will it resubscribe.

It's different with asynchronous streams, e.g. created with `Flux.interval`.

```
Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .doOnNext(__ -> System.out.println("producing number: " + __))
    .publish()
    .autoConnect()
    .doOnNext((Integer __) -> {
        System.out.println("throwing error.");
        throw new RuntimeException("aaa");
    })
    .retry(1)
    .subscribe()
```

When you call `.subscribe()` then `retry` will internally call subscribe on `doOnNext` and so on until the first `doOnNext` calls `subscribe` on the Flux. The interval Flux says "Ok, I'll emit the first value in one second" and the subscription is established.

After one second a value is emitted, an error is thrown, the retry operator subscribes again.

In your example the Flux already starts emitting values during the subscribe call, before the subscription is fully established, so so speak.

Comment: `...the subscribe function inside the retry operator runs until the inner stream completes. Only then will it resubscribe.` Thanks. Also, can you explain in more details your last paragraph? (`subscribe functions will return` - `subscribe`of which operation? What did you mean by `return`? Why things work as I expected?)

Comment: @StavAlfi I've added some paragraphs. While the basic principles are easy to understand it can actually take a long time and a lot of practice to fully comprehend the mechanics of streams. And even then examples like yours can't be explained without thinking a while :)